# How can this ACARS message be decoded?

Tags: acars

With regards to the text below, can someone offer either advice or a link to a website/document that would help decode ACARS messages.

I am ok with the following:

- QU - ACARS "to" address
- Q - ACARS "from" address
- FML - data from left hand FMS
- FI - Flight Identifier
- AN - Aircraft Number
- IGW1 - Iridium server identifier
- 130710 - date/time of data package sent
- F57A - package identifier

So that leaves the DT QXT info plus the hex from ADS line.

```
QU REKASCC    
.QXSXMXS 130710    
FML    
FI AB1234/AN G-INFO    
DT QXT IGW1 130710 F57A    
-  ADS.TF- 
AMU0719603F0D994AFD09849D0D1B05B71C71CAFC85601FFFFF55554AFC800E0EB0F57FF40F0E29AA3FF4100EB11E0E8EFE
```

Comment: Welcome to aviation.SE. Could you please be more explicit on what you do and do not understand? QXT is one, could you list all the terms that you are missing? This will help in giving you a better answer.

Comment: As @Federico says, a list of what you understand and what you don't, will be helpful in providing a good answer. I've modified your question, so that it is much more understandable, but you can always roll-back to your original question, if you don't like the new one. Welcome to Aviation.SE! : )

Comment: For another flight I've managed to get it to convert to this but it's the text on the DT line and POS line that I need help with. Also is there a list of acronyms such as "QXT" that might be available somewhere?

QU CPYXXXX
.REKASCC 161345
 FML
FI AA0000/AN G-INFO
DT QXT IGW1 161345 F64A
-  POSN70071W097007,,134460,360,DERLI,135460,DUKPA,M55,29530,1276,84,CDEB

Answer (score 4):

ACARS encoding is usually different from customer to customer.  Decoding it can be very difficult, even if you have access to the aircraft to have some idea of what is being sent.  Usually, the manufacturer won't share the details with anyone other than the original customer, expecting subsequent operators to pay for custom coding on the ACARS.  A general introduction to the basic standard codes can be found here; www.universal-radio.com/catalog/decoders/acarsweb.pdf .   The 'out return in' messages are pretty much standard.  No doubt there are enthusiasts out there who have decoded at least parts of the carrier specific/aircraft specific coding.  I worked with an ACARS equipped fleet where most of the messages sent were carrier specific and I never did manage to get the decode of the top of climb (TOC), cruise (CRZ) and top of descent (TOD) reports that were being sent automatically, despite the co-operation of the vender and the original customer, as the original customer had thrown that information away.

LIkely decode from the data you have supplied;

POSN70071W097007 = Postion North 70 degrees 07.1 minutes, West 9 degrees 00.7 minutes.

Sorry, it isn't much.  G-INFO isn't the registration either, it would seem.  Registration information is usually hard encoded in a custom plug for each aircraft's ACARS system.

Comment: "*G-INFO isn't the registration either*", it's the name given by CAA to their [aircraft register](https://www.caa.co.uk/aircraft-register/g-info/search-g-info/).